# How do i make spans align

Tags: css, alignment

Im trying to get my bars to align in a straight line after the text. They are drawn using css and animated with jQuery. The spans are triggered when i use the div class"meter orange" and using the span style's width sets the size of the progress bars.

```
<div class="meter orange">HTML
<span style="width: 65.3%"></span>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot Link]

**CSS:**

```
    #progress-bars-page-wrap { 
    width: 490px; 
    margin: 80px auto; 
    }

    .meter { 
        height: 8px;  /* Can be anything */
        position: relative;
        padding: 3px;

    }
    .meter > span {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgb(43,194,83);

    }

    .orange > span {
        background-color: #e94939;

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bars.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".meter > span").each(function() {
            $(this)
                .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
                .width(0)
                .animate({
                    width: $(this).data("origWidth")
                }, 900);
        });
    });
</script>


</head>

<body>

<div id="progress-bars-page-wrap">

    <div class="meter orange">Javascript<span style="width: 33.3%"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter orange">HTML
        <span style="width: 65.3%"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter orange">CSS
        <span style="width: 70.3%"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter orange">Java
        <span style="width: 60%"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter orange">Python
        <span style="width: 84%"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter orange">.Net
        <span style="width: 32%"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter orange">Ajax
        <span style="width: 60%"></span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For reference: I'm about 74% certain it's not valid to set a width on an inline element.  If you're gonna put `display: block` on a span, you might as well make it a div...

Comment: Do you mean for validation purposes? I wont validate anyway because my template is going to have a lot of HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done by setting a width to the element on the left. You can set the `width` and `height` of inline elements (`<span>`) by setting `display:inline-block`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUnrj/1/)

**CSS**

```
.meter .label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:4em;
}
.meter .bar {
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="meter orange nostripes">
    <span class="label">Javascript</span>  
    <span class="bar" style="width: 33.3%"></span>
</div>
```

### Warning

This method will run into issue though if you want to style at width:100% because the left `<span>` is taking up room so the bar will be wrapper to the next line. We can get around this by using `position:absolute` on `.label` and giving `.bar` a `margin-left` of the same size as `.label`.

[jsFiddle (CSS bar is `width:100%`)](http://jsfiddle.net/dUnrj/3/)

```
.meter .label {
    position:absolute;
}
.meter .bar {
    margin-left:4em;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the text out of the animation? As the bars are sliding out the text slides out into view with them. I would like to keep the text stationary and just have the bars move.

Comment: Its still animating. Instead of the animation flowing through the text and drawing the bars it is animating the text from 0% to the set percentage and doing the same thing to the bars.

Comment: I forgot to press Save Edits, try the last Fiddle again.

Answer (score 0):

Put `<span>`s around the programming languages and set their fixed width equal to the same number of pixels.  That way each programming language will take up the same amount of space, which will lead to the bars starting at the same point on each line.

CSS:

```
.programmingLang {width: 100px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="meter orange">Javascript<span style="width: 33.3%"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter orange"><span class="programmingLang">HTML</span>
        <span style="width: 65.3%"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter orange"><span class="programmingLang">CSS</span>
        <span style="width: 70.3%"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

If you were not able to change the HTML I am pretty sure you could just add this:

```
.meter span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px; /* adjust to fit label length */
}
```